# Vieweing the most derived type in the debugger (RTTI enabled)

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, rtti

Consider the following code compiled with RTTI enabled

```
class Base 
{
    virtual void f(); //without this, typeid won't show the most derived type
};
class Derived : public Base {};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Base* b = new Derived();
    std::cout << typeid(*b).name() << std::endl; //this works but not on the Watch wnd
    return 0; //breakpoint here
}
```

If I break at the `return` line and look in the Watch panel at the `b` variable, the type column will say `Base` and not `Derived`. Using [AutoExp.dat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097579/how-do-i-get-the-vs-debugger-to-display-the-type-name-of-an-object-member) I can have the most-derived type displayed for specific base classes, but I want to be able to do that for all types. I've tried using `typeid(b)` in the Watch and Immediate windows to no avail - I get `CXX0017: Error: symbol "typeid" not found`. I have also tried typing `b,t` (*Autoexp.dat* syntax) in the Watch window - but then I get `CXX0026: Error: bad format string`

Comment: RTTI is too primitive to allow this.  You know that the object is actually a Derived*, the debugger doesn't.  So help it along, type `(Derived*)b` in the watch expression.

Comment: But the debugger can run commands, can it not? why won't it accept the `typeid` operator ? (I mean in the watch/command window)

Comment: Also, if I used <,t> in autoexp.dat I *would* see the most derived type in the watch windows

Comment: The watch window does not actually compile c++ code.  It is more like an interpreter that knows most c++ constructs, and has access to your program's memory map.   It doesn't have to implement typeid.  (I think)

Comment: @AShelly does the same apply to the immediate window? If so, I guess that means the VS debugger doesn't expose an ability it definitely has (as suggested by `autoexp.dat`'s `<,t>` format)

Comment: in fact, `<,t>` does not produce correct result, e.g. it might be different from __vfptr (vtable pointer that points to most derived type's table)